# How to create seat picker or seat map in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Apologies if my question isn't specific. Also, I am new to ReactJS.

I am planning to create seat picker for airline application I am working on. The seat map should contain different seats such as seats for disable, passenger with infant, etc. The map should also show whether the seat is available or not. I would like you to guide me the followings:

1. Is there any existing library you recommend? Can I easily customize it such as colors, number of rows and columns,override methods, etc?
2. Do you think that is it easily done if I create it from scratch?
3. Is there any resources I can look at in order to study and tackle similar problems

Comment: Have you found or tired writing something so far? That would be a better approach to receving an answer on SO :)

Comment: This is a very generic question ... I've worked on multiple solution and they're not similar. Unless you define your problem well and show what you've tried asking that question on SO won't help

Answer (score 4):

My approach would be:

1. Make a JSON representation of the plane
2. Store this data in a Store (read about the React Context API a bit)
3. Visualize the data in a UI
4. Attach click handlers to the seats
5. Toggle availability onClick with actions and reducers (read about the React Context API a bit).

Example of the plain's JSON (unfinished): https://jsonblob.com/e053de37-0c6e-11ea-833d-03b561efe969

Read about the context API here: https://www.codementor.io/maksimivanov/react-context-api-u6rox74dv

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question:

> 1. Is there any existing library you recommend? Can I easily customize it such as colors, number of rows and columns,override methods, etc?

I looked on [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/) and found [react-seat-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-seat-picker). This should help with initial findings.